# Can anyone explain interesting spin-lock behavior?

Tags: scala, concurrency, spinlock

Given the following code

```
case class Score(value: BigInt, random: Long = randomLong) extends Comparable[Score] {

  override def compareTo(that: Score): Int = {
    if (this.value < that.value) -1
    else if (this.value > that.value) 1
    else if (this.random < that.random) -1
    else if (this.random > that.random) 1
    else 0
  }

  override def equals(obj: _root_.scala.Any): Boolean = {
    val that = obj.asInstanceOf[Score]
    this.value == that.value && this.random == that.random
  }
}

@tailrec
private def update(mode: UpdateMode, member: String, newScore: Score, spinCount: Int, spinStart: Long): Unit = {
  // Caution: there is some subtle logic below, so don't modify it unless you grok it

  try {
    Metrics.checkSpinCount(member, spinCount)
  } catch {
    case cause: ConcurrentModificationException =>
      throw new ConcurrentModificationException(Leaderboard.maximumSpinCountExceeded.format("update", member), cause)
  }

  // Set the spin-lock
  put(member, None) match {
    case None =>
      // BEGIN CRITICAL SECTION
      // Member's first time on the board
      if (scoreToMember.put(newScore, member) != null) {
        val message = s"$member: added new member in memberToScore, but found old member in scoreToMember"
        logger.error(message)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException(message)
      }
      memberToScore.put(member, Some(newScore)) // remove the spin-lock
      // END CRITICAL SECTION
    case Some(option) => option match {
      case None =>            // Update in progress, so spin until complete
        //logger.debug(s"update: $member locked, spinCount = $spinCount")
        for (i <- -1 to spinCount * 2) {Thread.`yield`()} // dampen contention
        update(mode, member, newScore, spinCount + 1, spinStart)
      case Some(oldScore) =>
        // BEGIN CRITICAL SECTION
        // Member already on the leaderboard
        if (scoreToMember.remove(oldScore) == null) {
            val message = s"$member: oldScore not found in scoreToMember, concurrency defect"
            logger.error(message)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException(message)
          } else {
            val score =
              mode match {
                case Replace =>
                  //logger.debug(s"$member: newScore = $newScore")
                  newScore
                case Increment =>
                  //logger.debug(s"$member: newScore = $newScore, oldScore = $oldScore")
                  Score(newScore.value + oldScore.value)
              }
            //logger.debug(s"$member: updated score = $score")
            scoreToMember.put(score, member)
            memberToScore.put(member, Some(score))  // remove the spin-lock
            //logger.debug(s"update: $member unlocked")
          }
        // END CRITICAL SECTION
        // Do this outside the critical section to reduce time under lock
        if (spinCount > 0) Metrics.checkSpinTime(System.nanoTime() - spinStart)
    }
  }
}
```

There are two important data structures: memberToScore and scoreToMember. I have experimented using both `TrieMap[String,Option[Score]]` and `ConcurrentHashMap[String,Option[Score]]` for memberToScore and both have the same behavior.

So far my testing indicates the code is correct and thread safe, but the mystery is the performance of the spin-lock. On a system with 12 hardware threads, and 1000 iterations on 12 Futures: hitting the same member all the time results in spin cycles of 50 or more, but hitting a random distribution of members can result in  spin cycles of 100 or more. The behavior gets worse if I don't dampen the spin without iterating over yield() calls.

So, this seems counter intuitive, I was expecting the random distribution of keys to result in less spin than the same key, but testing proves otherwise.

**Can anyone offer some insight into this counter-intuitive behavior?**

Granted there may be better solutions to my design, and I am open to them, but for now I cannot seem to find a satisfactory explanation for what my tests are showing, and my curiosity leaves me hungry.

As an aside, while the single member test has a lower ceiling for the spin count, the random member test has a lower ceiling for time spinning, which is what I would expect. I just cannot explain why the random member test generally produces a higher ceiling for spin count.

Comment: Do you get `ConcurrentModificationException`s? Especially the ones triggered inside the spin lock? It seems, you'd get a permanent lock if those are thrown. And it seems possible to trigger them. You have a `scoreToMember` structure, but what happens if two members have the same score? It seems to me, it will result in inconsistent state, an exception thrown and a permanent lock.

Comment: Consider the following `update` sequences (starting from empty board, fully sequential, no concurrency, done with mode=Replace): 1) `update("A", 10); update("B", 10)` => exception thrown from `case None` branch, permanent lock on `"B"`. 2) `update("A", 10); update("B", 20); update("A", 20); update("B", 30); update("A", 40)` => exception from `case Some(oldScore)` branch, permanent lock on `"A"`.

Comment: The only ConcurrentModificationException I ever see are the ones I throw, such as when the spin-lock spins too many times. I do not expect to get ConcurrentModificationException  from operations on either TrieMap or ConcurrentHashMap, and have never seen such. The scoreToMember is a ConcurrentSkipListMap, so I do not expect to see ConcurrentModificationExceptions from there, nor have I. A Score has two parts, a BigInt score and a Long random number to break ties. While it is mathematically possible for a tie score, the probability is about 1 / maxLong.

Comment: I tried to run your code with some appropriate definitions and I couldn't reproduce this problem. It works like you'd intuitively expect. It looks as if there were a bug in some other part of the code. Can you show the definition of `Score`? Or even a complete minimal example that exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: Added Score to the source code. If you want to see the whole project, it's at https://github.com/kolotyluk/leaderboard - but I have made a few improvements which mitigate the problem. In particular, playing around with `for (i <- -1 to spinCount * 2) {Thread.`yield`()} // dampen contention` makes a world of difference.

Comment: If you replace `for ...` with just `Thread.yield()` then the problem becomes most obvious. Using exponential back-off seems to mitigate things best. `for (i <- -1 to spinCount * spinCount) Thread.yield`